# Specifying where columns should be placed in r

Tags: r, calculated-columns

When I create a new variable, is there a way to specify in the function where to place it?

Right now, it adds it to the end of the dataframe, but for ease of viewing in Excel for example, I'd like to place a new calculated column beside the columns I used for the calculation.

Here's an example of code:

```
rawdata2 <- (rawdata1 %>% unite(location, locations1,locations2, locations3, 
                           na.rm = TRUE, remove=TRUE) 
                %>%  select(-location7, -location16)
                %>% unite(Sector, Sectors, na.rm=TRUE, remove=TRUE)
                %>% unite(TypeofSpace, TypesofSpace, type.of.spaceOther, na.rm=TRUE, 
remove=TRUE)
                
        )
```

Comment: Maybe add a `%>% select(variables names)` at the end, where you can modify the order of the variables in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange the columns in your data frame.  It looks like you are using `dplyr::select` in your example.

```
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
      select(mpg, carb, everything())  ## moves carb up behind mpg
head(mtcars2)
#                   mpg carb cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear
# Mazda RX4         21.0    4   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0    4   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4
# Datsun 710        22.8    1   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4    1   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7    2   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3
# Valiant           18.1    1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3
```

You can do the same thing with base subsetting, for example with a data frame with 11 columns you can move the 11th behind the second by

```
mtcars3 <- mtcars[,c(1,11,2:10)]
identical(mtcars2, mtcars3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! I have 325 columns in my dataframe - is there a way to use colnames to say "in between"? - because I dont want to write out all of them, I know you use everything, but the columns I'm manipulating are in between - I guess I could move all to the end

Comment: The first example, using `select` uses column names. I think the documentation for select has a bunch of options for how you specify columns, for example using `last_col()` or `starts_with()` (for example) to choose columns without typing all of them out.

Comment: thanks. This looks useful too: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using relocate, documentation here: dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html